# Required Xpath Logic

Tags: xpath

I am developing a data scraping program by using xulrunner and .net I and able to achieve all the thing just I am unable to implement the logic to find similar elements on page ,details are as below

1) If I select any element/text then I get its xpath so I wish 
Selects all similar elements page wide.I think we can achieve this by  removing the position part from the selection xpath.

2) If I select any element/text then I get its xpath so I wish 
Selects all similar elements next to the selected element

3)If I select any element/text then I get its xpath so I wish 
Selects all similar elements within the parent element

I am really unable to understand how to implement it

Comment: I suggest you to install firefox plugin xpather, then play with it a little. You can just choose something in the screen and it will give you the xpath for it, then you can change the generated xpath and it will show what it matches in the page. Then I think you'll have a better idea of how it works. Of course, when you have an xpath and it returns a single element, you can always remove the last part of it and test if it still returns a single element or a list of elements...

Comment: hi thanks for comment the issue i am facing is that evey time position part gets changes for example i got following xpath if i select one title  (//div[4]/div[@class='clearfix']/div[@class='MT_20'][1]/div[@class='MT_20'][1]/div[@class='serp_tp_list ']/a[@class='underlineNone jqPaidBusinessLink']/div[@class='header2 clearfix']/div[@class='FL'][1]/h2[@class='listingName']) in this case how can my program manipulate staing to remove string part because position part gets change for every xpath

Comment: I can't really tell without seeing your html. Do you think you can post it or send me some link?